# advantage of using a trigger to populate surrogate key in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on a codebase which has the following type of pattern for generating surrogate key for tables.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TEST_TRIG
BEFORE INSERT  OR UPDATE
ON my_table
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN
      IF NVL(:NEW.column1, 0) = 0 THEN
         SELECT my_table_seq.NEXTVAL
         INTO  :NEW.column1
         FROM  dual;

      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

And the PL/SQL logic that calls this code as,

```
begin
     insert into my_table(0);
end;
```

My question is What is the need for a trigger?
Why not just do a,

```
insert into my_table(my_table_seq.next_val)
```

and call it a day?
Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you could also omit sequences and keep track of assigned IDs in a regular table. When you have a feature that saves work and prevent human errors, you simply use it ;-)

Comment: One could also wonder why it's an `INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger when the body ignores updates.

Comment: in practice, you probably have more columns - and it would be good for the case when this one was left off the INSERT/

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Agreed. That question was in my mind too.. But this one bothered me the most :-p

Comment: @Randy: Wouldn't it be much more simpler to have the column with the NOT NULL UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: As to the question, I think it's the mostly to not have to debug problems where you accidentally use the wrong sequence in an insert. Been there :-/

Comment: Re: NOT NULL and UNIQUE - those are fine constraints to have on a column but they don't get it POPULATED, which is kind of the point here. Also, if you do this in a trigger you DON'T end up having to debug all the times that programmers forget to add the "sequence.NEXT_VAL" call, or use the WRONG sequence, or find the max value of the key column and add 1, or all the other ways coders will manage to get it wrong.  Here's the secret to having a happy life - do this ONCE, in a TRIGGER, and be done with it.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular pattern is actually quite dangerous as it allows someone to manually input a new ID that might clash with an already extant surrogate key or one that your sequence might generate in the future.

Your trigger should really look like this to ensure that for every new record gets a unique key. If you're using 11.2 or higher there's no need for the `select ... into ...`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_TRIG
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.column1 := my_table_seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

The benefit of this approach is that it's *always* done. Whatever value anyone puts in for this column gets overwritten to something that will work and which uses the correct sequence; if someone forgets to add it in the statement will still work.

It makes it impossible to break your surrogate key.

With what you suggest, imagine that someone places a 1 instead; you get a primary key violation. If someone forgets then there's more errors. You'll never guarantee that every update to your table will be through a single point of entry so the trigger guarantees that the PK is populated correctly.

It's worth noting that from 12c you can use an [identity column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7002.htm#CJAHCAFF), which makes explicit the link between table and auto-increment; there's no need for a trigger or a sequence. The syntax for the table creation DDL would be:

```
create table <table_name> ( <column_name> generated as identity );
```

Comment: I tend to disagree. Insert triggers that always set the PK without checking if the user provided a sensible default make syncing data between database instances much harder. Of course you can disable the trigger, do your insert, and enable it again, but that usually results in someone forgetting to enable the trigger afterwards.

Comment: But if a PK is sequence generated there is no sensible default that can be guaranteed to not clash with a sequence value @Frank. You're setting yourself up to have some random statements fail in the future.

Comment: Thanks Ben. It makes sense. I am at a loss to understand why did they decide add that NVL() at all. Clearly, A non-colliding key greater than the current value of the sequence can be inserted as you have mentioned.

Comment: @Ben You're right. But if I update the sequence value as well to max(pk) + 1, I'm on the safe side again.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger and insert statement both have different functionalists 
if you want just to insert the data and put no logs for that insertion than this insert Statement would be fine but that you can be sure of integrity of the data in table as it can be modified by a number of sources on the other hand if you want logs for every insert/update statement fired on the table irrespective of the call in your block triggers would be helpful and data integrity can be given a check at any point of time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Darn!!, Is that a single sentence??