# Does Oracle use short-circuiting logical operators?

Tags: oracle

Test replica of the database uses following trigger

```
TRIGGER "BINFO_TEST"."SPK_COMPANY" 
  before insert or update on "COMPANY"
  for each row
begin
  if inserting then
    if :NEW."ID" is null then
      select SEQ_COMPANY.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual;
    end if;
  end if;
  select sysdate into :NEW."DATE_CREATED" from dual;
end;
```

I use Entity Framework and ID is mapped to `decimal` type, meaning that it is not nullable. By default if I **insert** a value 0 is passed and trigger is skipped. Does oracle triggers use "short-circuiting" logical operators and can I use something like

```
TRIGGER "BINFO_TEST"."SPK_COMPANY" 
  before insert or update on "COMPANY"
  for each row
begin
  if inserting then
    if :NEW."ID" is null OR :NEW."ID" = 0 then
      select SEQ_COMPANY.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual;
    end if;
  end if;
  select sysdate into :NEW."DATE_CREATED" from dual;
end;
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you're using [a flawed model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17880500/458741) to populate your ID that will cause you problems in the future. Also, if you're on 11g or above there's no need for the select from dual, just assign directly. Whatever you're using you can assign sysdate directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is short-circuit evaluation in PL/SQL:

> When evaluating a logical expression, PL/SQL uses short-circuit evaluation. That is, PL/SQL stops evaluating the expression as soon as the result can be determined. This lets you write expressions that might otherwise cause an error.

Source: [Fundamentals of the PL/SQL Language](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/02_funds.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this little shorter:

```
begin
  if inserting then
    :NEW."ID" := NVL(NULLIF(:NEW."ID",0), SEQ_COMPANY.NEXTVAL);
  end if;
  :NEW."DATE_CREATED" := sysdate;
end;
```